# How to check Spark Version

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cloudera

I want to check the spark version in cdh 5.7.0. I have searched on the internet but not able to understand. Please help.

Comment: See [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question) on [meta].

Comment: but i tried few things before posting it. I didn't find any help thats why i posted here

Comment: Then show us your efforts.

Comment: Programmatically finding spark version would be best. That's for sure the one that my code is using. How to do it in python? Thanx

Comment: #print(pyspark.__version()__)
#print(pyspark.version())
import pyspark
#print(pyspark.version())
#print(pyspark.__version()__)
print(pyspark.__version__)  # this works

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Addition to @Binary Nerd

If you are using Spark, use the following to get the Spark version:

```
spark-submit --version
```

or

Login to the Cloudera Manager and goto Hosts page then run `inspect hosts in cluster`

Comment: I get "ga@ga-HP-Z820:/mnt/fastssd/bot_subreddit_recom$ spark-submit --version >spark-submit: command not found

Comment: Check your SPARK_HOME config

Comment: I got a `NameError: name 'submit' is not defined` error

Comment: can u share your command

Comment: Too bad the output has ridiculous ASCII art that makes it difficult to parse :(

Answer (score 33):

You can get the spark version by using the following command:

```
spark-submit --version

spark-shell --version

spark-sql --version
```

You can visit the below site to know the spark-version used in CDH 5.7.0

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_new_in_cdh_57.html#concept_m3k_rxh_1v

Comment: spark-sql --version is not working. Above two are working fine

Answer (score 2):

According to the Cloudera documentation - [What's New in CDH 5.7.0](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_new_in_cdh_57.html) it includes [Spark 1.6.0](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_new_in_cdh_57.html#concept_m3k_rxh_1v).