# Pyspark approxQuantile throwing error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have loaded one csv file into my spark dataframe, after that if I try to calculate using `approxQuantile` method which is giving me an error. Tried with different data set and different columns, probablibities, and relativeError. Help me out understanding what's going on.

```py
df.approxQuantile("column_name", [0.2,0.3,0.6,1.0], 0)
```

I am getting the following error :

> py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o30.approxQuantile. Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method approxQuantile([class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon, class java.lang.Double]) does not exist at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: What's your data type (`df.printSchema()`)?

Comment: All columns are of type "integer" 
root
 |-- j: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- f: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- l: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- e: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- g: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- h: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- m: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- k: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- d: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- i: integer (nullable = true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if your pyspark driver is using Spark 2.2.0 and your Spark cluster is running 2.1.1 (or earlier). Ensure that your driver & cluster versions match and you should be good to go!

See the note in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.approxQuantile) about a change to the interface for approxQuantile in 2.2:

> Changed in version 2.2: Added support for multiple columns.

Comment: How to fix this error? And how to find out which are the versions of pyspark driver and spark cluster ?

Comment: To fix, find out if your driver or your cluster is running the older version. Then upgrade that component to match the version the other is running
 (probably by downloading from Spark's website). See here to determine your spark version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586834/how-to-check-spark-version . It also looks like you're using pyspark. You can see your pyspark version with this: pip freeze | grep spark