# How to check pyspark version using jupyter notbook

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Hi I'm using Jupyterlab 3.1.9. Can you tell me how do I fund my pyspark version using jupyter notebook in Jupyterlab
Tried following code

```
from pyspark 
import SparkContext 
sc = SparkContext("local", "First App") 
sc.version
```

But I'm not sure if it's returning pyspark version of spark version

Comment: `spark.version`?

Comment: @blackbishop, I tried `from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "First App")
sc.version` But I'm not sure if it's giving pyspark version or spark version

Comment: Why do you think they are different? Pyspark is just Python API to use Spark. both `sc.version` and `spark.version` give you the version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586834/how-to-check-spark-version

Answer (score 2):

You can check on jupyter by these method.

[image]

Comment: Who puts a screenshot of a command? Copy paste this: `import pyspark; print(pyspark.__version__)`